# Permission denied opening UDP socket with static IP

Tags: networking, static-ip, sockets

I have made a Linux program that sends UDP packets to a lighting controller. This works under both Ubuntu and Mac OS X. I configured an ethernet port to have a static IP address (with the correct netmask). The ethernet cable pugs straight from the controller device into the Pi.

The app runs on the Pi but I get a 'permission denied' error when trying to open a UDP socket. I edited the `dhcpcd.conf` file as per [these](http://j0hn.uk/static-ip/) instructions, so I am now able to ping the box and open its web interface in browser; yet I still get the error.

My settings are:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.0.1.10/24
static routers=10.0.1.1
static domain_name_servers=10.0.1.1
```

The device's IP is `10.0.1.101`, so I have also tried setting those `routers` and `domain_name_servers`, to that; but that didn't work either. Is there some additional network configuration I should try that includes specifying the netmask or something?

Any advice is appreciated!

EDIT - It turns out that this only happens when trying to connect to the broadcast IP (10.0.1.255), the other IP works fine. I do need to be able to broadcast though so still looking for a solution...

Comment: it could be selinux

Comment: I don't know why you want  static address, but it might work if you used a consistent network setting.

Comment: Don't expect other people to bother spending much time contemplating someone else's problem if that someone else A) Cannot bother to post the code that produced the error, B) Cannot bother to include the literal text of the error.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro - I am using a vanilla raspbian install so selinux shouldn't an issue, no?

Comment: @Milliways - I need a static address as the device has a fixed IP I need to talk to - not sure what you mean by 'consistent network setting'

Comment: @goldilocks - I has assumed this was the wrong place to post the c++ code I had written although the app runs fine on Ubuntu so also assumed it was specific to my Pi network setup and was hoping I missed something simple. However, the app is written for the [cinder](http://libcinder.org) framework implementing [this](https://github.com/naychrist/cinder-ddp) library which wraps [this one](https://github.com/BanTheRewind/Cinder-Asio)

(apologies I needed to break these responses up due to forum limitations - not sure if a better way)

Comment: "It runs fine on computer A" does not mean the code is correct. You're right, this is a grey area WRT to appropriateness here, but if you suspect it may have something to due with the pi in particular, then that's fine. Note that very few people will want to look through your whole project; generally when trying to isolate problems and particularly when asking for other people for help spotting them, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is essential. I'm not closing this question or anything, just suggesting to you some things you might want to consider if you want to deal with this efficiently.

Comment: You are using `10.0.10` on a network with `10.0.1`

Comment: @Milliways - thanks for spotting that but it actually is 10.0.1 on my machine, just made a typo when posting - edited. got my hopes up there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Static addresses have nothing to do with it. Sending to a broadcast address is a privileged operation. You either need to be root, or you need to have the CAP_NET_ADMIN (and hopefully some day the CAP_NET_BROADCAST) capability.

Comment: thanks, didn't even think to try running it as root! the boxes are installed somewhere for a couple more weeks but will try and test this when I get them back.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your network mask ? IP addresses starting between 0 and 127 should be associated to class A IP networks, with a network mask of /8 or 255.0.0.0.

In this case, your broadcast address would be 10.255.255.255, I guess.

Comment: 10.0.1.10/24 is a legitimate IP address/subnet mask. The subnets have just been made smaller, that is all. I have worked at many multinationals where this is used.

Comment: the device I am talking to is configured for a network mask of 255.255.255.0, which an ifconfig reveals to be true also on my Pi. So I normally use a broadcast IP of 10.0.1.255, which also shows up when running ifconfig on the Pi. I have never used dhcpcd.conf before but seems like this is behaving correctly.

Comment: @Greenonline : I never said it was technically invalid.

Comment: network "classes" have not been an issue since the early 90s.